# How to get new photo and text displayed for each day of the week?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, photo

I am working on a little Javascript project to get the day of the week displayed. I have that part down, but I would also like to have a photo to also represent each day of the week. Is there a way to utilize both text and a photo together in an array item? I have been searching for a while, and the only examples I can find are to get a random photo app, which is not what I need.

[My Day Tracker Project](https://codepen.io/mbert86/pen/oQYeao)

```
var d = new Date();
var days = ["Sunday",
"Monday",
"Tuesday",
"Wednesday",
"Thursday",
"Friday",
"Saturday"];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days[d.getDay()];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new array for photos:

```
var photos = [
  'https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals',
  'https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch',
  'https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature',
  'https://placeimg.com/640/480/people',
  'https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech',
  'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any',
  'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any'
];
```

Add an empty image tag:

```
<img id="image">
```

Setup the src attribute:

```
document.getElementById("image").src = photos[d.getDay()];
```

[working code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NEbwpv)

Answer (score 0):

You could update your array to look like this:

```
var days = 
[

{name: "Monday",    img: "https://image.ibb.co/caPP3V/all.jpg"},
{name: "Tuesday",   img: "https://image.ibb.co/btn2OV/dontgrowup.jpg"},
{name: "Wednesday", img: "https://image.ibb.co/kQoHOV/everything-Sux.jpg"},
{name: "Thursday",  img: "https://image.ibb.co/c2UP3V/enjoy.jpg"},
{name: "Friday",    img: "https://image.ibb.co/ifbFAA/college.jpg.jpg"},
{name: "Saturday",  img: "https://image.ibb.co/fe7Yxq/hyper.jpg"},
{name: "Sunday",    img: "https://image.ibb.co/dKtj3V/cooltobeyou.jpg"}

]
```

Then to show the day of the week you will then need to add ***.name*** at the end

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days[d.getDay()].name;
```

To show the image for that day, just create an img in the html

```
<img id="image">
```

And you can then update the src of that image in a similar way

```
document.getElementById("image").src= days[d.getDay()].img;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think it would be simpler if *days* is an object with `{dayname: imageURI}`, and just lower case the day name, otherwise you have to loop over the array to find the right object (or make Sunday the first object in the array). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Change your array structure to add a image properties like below.

```
  var days = [
     {
       day: "day name",
       image: "image path"
     }
  ];
```

**Working solution**

```js
    var d = new Date();
    var days = [
      {
        day: "Sunday",
        image:
          "http://wearesunday.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/sunday-logo.png"
      },
      {
        day: "Monday",
        image:
          "https://www.monday.vc/assets/share-mondayvc-259d07fc0eb8e761596a059e81111291e487be9fa24579cb49411c22190b3a97.png"
      },
      {
        day: "Tuesday",
        image:
          "https://goodlucksymbols.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Tuesday-Symbolism.jpg"
      },
      {
        day: "Wednesday",
        image:
          "https://www.thefactsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/wednesday-facts.jpg"
      },
      {
        day: "Thursday",
        image:
          "https://www.thefactsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/wednesday-facts.jpg"
      },
      {
        day: "Friday",
        image:
          "https://ihcapetown.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/friday-vintage-floral-lettering_23-2147659455.jpg"
      },
      {
        day: "Saturday",
        image:
          "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/04/19/29/saturday-706914_960_720.jpg"
      }
    ];

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days[d.getDay()].day;
    document.getElementById("container").style.background =
      "url('" + days[d.getDay()].image + "') no-repeat center";
```

```css
      html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      p {
        color: red;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #fff;
      }

      .container {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container"><p id="demo"></p></div>
```

Disclaimer: All the images are used here are taken from google images.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the day name in the host default language using the *weekday* option of [*Date.prototype.toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) and setting the language to *undefined*, e.g.

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString(undefined, {weekday:'long'}));
```

As others have said, getting the image can be done with an array of 7 image references (indexes 0 to 6) and setting the image based on the day number from *getDay*.

Answer (score 0):

https://keywordimg.com/640x480/any will always return a ramdom image for any keyword

```
var daysimages = 
[

{name: "Monday",    img: "https://keywordimg.com/640x480/monday"},
{name: "Tuesday",   img: "https://keywordimg.com/640x480/tuedy"},
{name: "Wednesday", img: "https://keywordimg.com/640x480/wednesday"},
{name: "Thursday",  img: "https://keywordimg.com/640x480/thursday"},
{name: "Friday",    img: "https://keywordimg.com/640x480/fiday"},
{name: "Saturday",  img: "https://keywordimg.com/640x480/saturday"},
{name: "Sunday",    img: "https://keywordimg.com/640x480/sunday"}

]


document.getElementById("demodays").innerHTML = daysimages[d.getDay()].name;
```

Code to display image for that day:

```
<img id="daysimage">
```

Edit the code to display the day:

```
document.getElementById("daysimage").src= days[d.getDay()].img;
```